# A question on Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds

For a Lie derivative $\mathscr{L}_{X} Y$ of $Y$ with respect to $X$, we mean that for two smooth vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a smooth manifold $M$ such that the following holds
$$
\mathscr{L}_{X} Y = \underset{t \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{(\varphi_{-t})_{\star} Y - Y}{t}, \tag{1}
$$
where $\varphi_{t}$ is a local one-parameter transformation group generated by $X$.

Suppose $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times U$ is the domain of $\varphi_{t}(p)$, where $U$ is an open subset of $M$. Then we can rewrite $(1)$ as the form
$$
(\mathscr{L}_{X} Y)_{p} = \underset{t \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{(\varphi_{-t})_{\star} Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)} - Y_p}{t}. \tag{2}
$$

We regard the tangent vector $(\varphi_{-t})_{\star} Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}$ as a map from an open subset of $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ into the tangent space $T_p M$.

**My question is**:

**$1$**. For an appropriate domain of $F$, why this map $F: t \mapsto (\varphi_{-t})_{\star} Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}$ is smooth ? However, the mooth structure on $T_p M$ has been still unclear to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $Y_{\varphi_t(p)}$ is certainly smooth in $t$, and the tangent map $(\varphi_{-t})_\star$ is smooth too.

Comment: Think about matrix multiplication of a $t$-parameterized matrix with a $t$-parameterized vector.

Comment: @Troy Woo: Thank you for your answer. However, I am a beginner in manifolds and I don't understand your not too specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $Y$ is smooth in the variable $p$, and now $Y_{\varphi_t(p)}$ (or maybe this notation: $Y_{p(t)}$) is just the restriction of $p$ to the integral curve, and therefore also smooth. Think of it as a composition of the smooth map $t\mapsto p(t)$ with $p\mapsto Y_p$.

On the other hand, $(\varphi_{-t})_\star$ is nothing but a jacobian (linear map) parameterized by $t$, which is smooth since $\varphi_{-t}$ is.

It suffices to consider the smoothness of $t\mapsto (\varphi_{-t})_\star Y_{\varphi_t(p)}$ in local coordinates, which is the multiplication of a matrix corresponding to $(\varphi_{-t})_\star$ and a column vector corresponding to $Y_{\varphi_t(p)}$, which are both smooth in $t$.

Comment: From your proof, I have some confusions: The smoothness of $(\varphi_{-t})_{\star}$ seems not obvious to me. Specifically, $(\varphi_{-t})_{\star}$ is a map from $T_{\varphi_{t}(p)} M$ into $T_{p}M$. If $t$ changes, the domain of $(\varphi_{-t})_{\star}$ make corresponding changes. Hence, we have $(\varphi_{-t})_{\star} (Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}) = \sum_{i}(\sum_{j} y^{j}_{\varphi_{t}(p)} A^i_j(t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_{p}$, in which $y^{j}_{\varphi_{t}(p)}$ is the coefficient of $Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}$ and $A^i_j(t)$ is the Jacobian matrix. We get $A^i_j(t)$ is smooth with respect to $t$.

Comment: However, I don't know why $(\varphi_{-t})_{\star}$ ( with respect to $t$ ) is smooth if $A^i_j(t)$ and $y^i_{\varphi_{t}(p)}$ are both smooth ( with respect to $t$ ). Even there has no smooth structure which would have been constructed on $T_p M$.

Comment: I have found a complete proof of it for the map $F$ can be viewed as a curve in $TM$ ( not in $T_{p}M$ ). In fact, there exists a real number $\varepsilon_0 : 0<\varepsilon_0<\varepsilon$ such that $F : (-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0) \to TM$ is a smooth map. Then by your method you have metioned here, I finished the rest proof. Thank you!

Comment: @WangtFei You are welcome. $F$ is indeed a curve on the tangent bundle. Such notion is frequently used in Nomizu and Kobayashi.

Comment: Yes, $F$ is a curve on $T_p M$. Since $M$ is a $T_1$ space, hence $\left\{ p \right\}$ is a close subset in $M$. Then we have $T_p M = \pi^{-1}(p)$ is also a close subset in $TM$. Thus, the smoothness of $F(t)$ should be considered in an open subset which contains the curve $F$. Therefore, $TM$ is a simple way of that choice.